Specifying Column Width
I have been looking for codes to specify column widths with alignment provided. That is when I met the code {tabular}{|wc{2cm}| what is wc?

wc{2cm} is centered of width 2cm (but no linebreaks) → Table 1 in the array documentation.

I prefer to write it as w{c}{2cm}, because w stands for “fixed width column” and takes two arguments: the first is one letter among r, c or l; the second is the width.
